# Update of latest kernel

Tags: kernel

I'm quite new to Ubuntu;
I read the following on this page:

> [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)
>
> "The latest kernel version any user is supposed to use in Ubuntu is updated automatically via the Update Manager, so no action is normally required by user regarding kernel upgrades."

By "updated automatically" and "no action is required" does this mean that the kernel installs itself in the background without me knowing (sounds more like something that Windows would do, not Linux) or is it supposed to appear in the Update Manager, then I click on "Install now" to install it?

Currently my Update manager tells me there's a new kernel to be installed, "Complete generic Linux kernel and headers" and "Ubuntu base" totaling 66MB.
If that's normal then I shall install them.
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to me to ask two unrelated questions (kernel updates and rootkit detection). Please split your question and ask a new one for the rootkit part while deleting those paragraphs here. Otherwise you won't get good answers because people having a solution for one problem maybe don't know how to solve the other...

Answer (score 3):

Comparing with mainline kernels, you don't need to pick a kernel version or manually download the deb files. That part is handled by Ubuntu. The only action left is installing the upgrades - for which, usually you have to manually allow the Update Manager to install updates. I'd modify that to "*extra* action" - nothing more than you'd need for any other package.

You can turn on unattended upgrades, then the kernel should be updated for security upgrades without asking you, but that's neither here nor there.